# How do I fix "Must use import to load ES Module" when using ts-node-dev

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

I am trying to get this simple typescript to work with ts-node-dev.

I am running the script using the following command:
`npx ts-node-dev ./src/index.ts`

The package.json is set to `"type": "module"`

**src/index.ts**

```
function sleep(ms: number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}

console.log('Hello World');
await sleep(1000);
console.log('Hello World later');

export {}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",                                  
    "module": "ESNext",                                
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  }
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
Compilation error in /../test/src/index.ts
Error: Must use import to load ES Module: /../test/src/index.ts
    at Object.<anonymous> (/../test/src/index.ts:1:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._compile (/home/max/.npm/_npx/2351b2a15f5189cb/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:568:25)
    at Module.m._compile (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-5564403295039684.js:69:33)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at require.extensions..jsx.require.extensions..js (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-5564403295039684.js:114:20)
    at require.extensions.<computed> (/tmp/ts-node-dev-hook-5564403295039684.js:71:20)
    at Object.nodeDevHook [as .ts] (/home/max/.npm/_npx/2351b2a15f5189cb/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/hook.js:63:13)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
[ERROR] 16:54:13 Error: Must use import to load ES Module: /../test/src/index.ts
```